# Cоздание нового окна

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Подскажите, как перенести введенные данные в textEdit, textEdit_2, textEdit_3
в новое окно по нажатию на кнопку pushButton_2 и как то их расположить, что б они не появились лишь бы где то.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(409, 223)
        MainWindow.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 251, 31))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 251, 31))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 100, 251, 31))
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 20, 61, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 70, 71, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 110, 121, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 140, 131, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 140, 121, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 409, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Имя"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Фамилия"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Дата рождения"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузить фото"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сгенерировать"))

class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton2.clicked.connect(self.clicked_button_2)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: прочитайте, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: @alexanderbarakin что не так с кодом? если сократить то там нечего и сокращать, в Ui_MainWindow находятся созданные элементы, я выделил с каких нужно считывать информацию, код предоставил в полном виде, что б его могли запустить на своем пк.

Comment: Тут опечатка: `self.ui.pushButton2`, кнопка то `pushButton_2`. Кст, в дизайнере называйте осмысленные названия в objectName, чтобы не было этих `pushButton_1` :) И используйте компоновщики (layout'ы), а то форма нерастягивая, некрасиво как-то :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте свой виджет-диалог с набором полей, и вызовите его при клике на кнопку, например:

```
...

class InfoDialogWidget(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, first_name, second_name, birthday):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Диалог')

        self.first_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(first_name)
        self.second_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(second_name)
        self.birthday = QtWidgets.QLabel(birthday)

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        main_layout.addRow('Имя', self.first_name)
        main_layout.addRow('Фамилия', self.second_name)
        main_layout.addRow('Дата рождения', self.birthday)

        self.setLayout(main_layout)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.show_info_dialog)

    def show_info_dialog(self):
        first_name = self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        second_name = self.ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText()
        birthday = self.ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText()

        dialog = InfoDialogWidget(self, first_name, second_name, birthday)
        # Запуск как модальный диалог
        dialog.exec()
        
        # Запуск как виджет, с show доступ к основному окну не будет блокироваться
        # Можно одновременно создавать несколько диалогов
        # dialog.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**PS.**

Для имени и фамилии лучше используйте [QLineEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QLineEdit.html#details), а для указания дня рождения кое-что более специализированное, например [QDateTimeEdit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetimeedit.html#details).

Для размещения виджетов вместо фиксированного положения и размера, помещайте их на компоновщики (layout), это может быть QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QFormLayout, QGridLayout. Они в дизайнере форм представлены не как виджеты, ищите их на панели инструментов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]